# without any X or without any Xs?

Tags: american-english, negation, singular-vs-plural

If we want to say without something, which one is generally true? (my example is car, but my question is for anything general)

1. without any car
2. without any cars
3. without cars
4. without car
5. with no car
6. with no cars

Comment: This depends on the noun being used and the specific context. There is no general answer.

Comment: Is there a rule that based on the noun we can find out what is correct to use?

Comment: Every one of your 6 options is valid in some context.

Comment: @Jim could you give an example sentence using #1 and 4?

Comment: @michael_timofeev- There were 7 of them and only 6 cars. They all  started running but with his bad leg her found himself in an empty lot **without any car** to take him the 5 miles in to town.

Comment: His car was in the shop again- it was always in the shop it seemed. He thought bitterly to himself,” My status is always “without car” these days.”

Answer (score 4):

By themselves, a few of those look confusing, but when given their own context, each example can make sense. So to answer your question, "which one is generally true," the short answer is: all of them.

1- Move all the cars from one lot to the other **without any car** getting scratched.

2- The commute is easy **without any cars** on the road.

3- The air we breathe would be cleaner **without cars**.

4- After I was mugged, I had to make my way home **without car**, keys or wallet.

5- Come on, dad, how are we going to cruise for chicks **with no car**?

6- A car salesman **with no cars** on the lot is very bored.

Answer (score 0):

All can be used depending on the context(to 4. you'd add the/a, usually).

If the place is expected to house many cars, you can say:

> The parking was without 'any cars / without cars / with no cars' in sight.

If a single car is expected, you can say:

> The garage was 'without any car / without the car / with no car' inside.

Answer (score -1):

For counting nouns, it's all plural: without any cars, with no cars, with cars. For mass nouns, no plural: without any water, with no water, with water.

Comment: As other users answered, it all depends on the context, and there are plenty of cases where you might say "without any *singular-noun*".